# Query within a specific range of line numbers from a xml file

Tags: xml, shell

I want to query `xml` file from lines to 1374-1601

I have tried this

```
$ sed -n '1374,1601p' *.xml | 
  xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//caldata[@chopper="on"]/c2[@unit="V/(nT*Hz)"]'
```

But I got

```
-:7.9: Extra content at the end of the document
        <caldata chopper="on" gain_1="0" gain_2="0" gain_3="0" impedance="(0,0)"
        ^
```

My idea was to select lines and then pipe these lines to xmlstartlet but hat does not work.

Part of the xml file

```
<channel id="2">
  <calibration>
    <cal_version>1.0</cal_version>
    <creator>software chcal 1.2</creator>
    <user>metronix</user>
    <calibrated_item>
      <ci identifier="coil">MFS07e</ci>
      <ci_serial_number>252</ci_serial_number>
      <ci_revision/>
      <ci_date>2013-01-24</ci_date>
      <ci_time>10:57:24</ci_time>
      <ci_calibration_valid_until/>
      <ci_next_calibration/>
      <ci_tag/>
      <ci_owner/>
      <ci_owners_address/>
      <ci_manufacturer>metronix</ci_manufacturer>
      <ci_manufacturers_address>Kocher Str. 3, 38120 Braunschweig, Germany</ci_manufacturers_address>
      <ci_comments/>
    </calibrated_item>
    <calibration_equipment>
      <ce/>
      <ce_serial_number/>
      <ce_revision/>
      <ce_date/>
      <ce_time/>
      <ce_calibration_valid_until>1970-01-01</ce_calibration_valid_until>
      <ce_next_calibration/>
      <ce_tag/>
      <ce_operator/>
      <ce_location>Magnetsrode</ce_location>
      <ce_contact_address>Kocher Str. 3, 38120 Braunschweig, Germany</ce_contact_address>
      <ce_comments/>
    </calibration_equipment>
    <calibration_protocol>
      <mtx>
        <mtx_serial_numer_engraved/>
        <mtx_preamplifier_serialnumber/>
        <mtx_ch1_div_ch2_at_1000gain_0dot025_hz/>
        <mtx_phase_deg_at_1000gain_0dot025_hz/>
        <mtx_ch1_div_ch2_at_1000gain_0dot025_hz_calibrated/>
        <mtx_phase_deg_at_1000gain_0dot025_hz_calibrated/>
        <rec_freq_resp_at_0dot_0025_to_100_hz_at_gain_1000/>
        <rec_freq_resp_at_0dot_0025_to_100_hz_at_gain_100/>
        <rec_freq_resp_at_0dot_0025_to_100_hz_at_gain_10/>
        <rec_freq_resp_at_0dot_0025_to_100_hz_at_gain_1/>
        <gain_factor_preamplifier/>
        <actual_sensitivity_ch2_by_ch1/>
        <actual_sensitivity_theta/>
        <calibrated_sensitivity_ch2_by_ch1/>
        <calibrated_sensitivity_theta/>
        <calibrated_cal_path_ch2_by_ch1/>
        <calibrated_cal_path_theta/>
        <calibrated_chopper_on/>
        <calibrated_chopper_off/>
        <calibrated_chopper_ukn/>
      </mtx>
    </calibration_protocol>
    <caldata chopper="on" gain_1="0" gain_2="0" gain_3="0" impedance="(0,0)">
      <c0 unit="V">0.00000000e+00</c0>
      <c1 unit="Hz">4.00000000e-01</c1>
      <c2 unit="V/(nT*Hz)">1.93430000e-02</c2>
      <c3 unit="deg">8.92260000e+01</c3>
    </caldata>
```

I have tried to use bichop's advice

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v \
'//channel[@id="2"]/caldata[@chopper="on"]/c2[@unit="V/(nT*Hz)"]'
```

but it does not work.

Here is my xml file

http://pastebin.com/0BJTAMGV

Comment: Does cutting at those lines result in a valid XML document?

Comment: @bishop I do not know,I have not worked with xml before.

Comment: Best to assume not. Since you're using an XPath in `xmlstartlet`, why not make that path more specific so as to find just the interesting subset of the XML?

Comment: @bishop Can you take a look at my edit,please!

Comment: The sample you have posted is not itself a valid XML document, which makes it hard for us to help out.  Please post sample data that we can use directly and that will clearly demonstrate the problem when we run your command line using the sample data, and rather than saying "it does not work" please give us specific error messages.

Comment: You can't edit XML safely that way. A snippet of an XML document without opening and closing tags is no longer the same document.

**Why** do you need those exact lines? Can you express the constraint that gives you those line numbers in a different way?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I need exactly these lines because they represent calibration of the equipment(at channel 2).If I use xmlstrarlet for whole xml,the result produced will contain calibration from other channels and that is not what  I want.I will add the whole xml file.

Comment: But you can tell XMLStarlet to provide only channel 2. Why not do that?

Comment: ...in fact, the answer by @larsks does exactly that (filtering by channel number).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy you'll note that my answer is actually using the query from the question, so credit to the poster for that solution :)

Comment: @RichardRublev, BTW, please avoid pastebin.com -- for anyone not running an adblocker it's full of ads. https://gist.github.com/ or http://ix.io/ are far better about that.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy ok,next time I will know!

Comment: ...so, you've got a bunch of different `channel[@id="2"]`s in that full document, but they're all in different enough places to make it pretty straightforward to find the right one. If you only want `/calibration_channels/channel[@id="2"]/calibration/caldata[@chopper="on"]`, well, that's not exactly a hard thing to write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `xmlstarlet` command at the end of your answer has some problems that mean it will never work.  The initial part of your query is...

```
//channel[@id="2"]/caldata[@chopper="on"]
```

...but according to your sample data, this will never match, because the `channel` element does not have any `caldata` elements as immediate children.  The tag hierarchy is:

```
channel
   calibration
     cal_version
     creator
     calibrated_item
     calibrated_equipment
     calibration_protocol
     caldata
     ...
```

So you would need at least:

```
//channel[@id="2"]/calibration/caldata[@chopper="on"]
```

Given your sample data, if I close off all the unclosed tags, I get:

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -v \
  '//channel[@id="2"]/calibration/caldata[@chopper="on"]' data.xml 
  0.00000000e+00
  4.00000000e-01
  1.93430000e-02
  8.92260000e+01
```

And in fact, with that one correction your entire query seems to work:

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -v \
  '//channel[@id="2"]/calibration/caldata[@chopper="on"]/c2[@unit="V/(nT*Hz)"]' data.xml
1.93430000e-02
```

Comment: If you look at the full document, btw, they actually have a lot of different `channel[@id="2"]`s, but the one they want is under `calibration_channels`

Answer (score 1):

If you cut a document to begin with `<channel id=2>`, it **must** end with a paired `</channel>` to still be a valid document. (Even then, if one of the parents contains a `xmlns=` declaration, you may have changed the semantics in a way that would invalidate otherwise-useful queries).

Since the end line you're querying doesn't contain `</channel>`, the subset you're cutting out of the document is not valid and cannot be parsed.

Adjust your line numbers accordingly, or -- by far the better approach -- **adjust your query to use the semantics of your document to address the specific region you want rather than a line-number range**.